How can I collapse long responses in my ChatGPT history?
I have accumulated a lot of history in ChatGPT, and since many of the responses are quite long, it is time-consuming to scroll through them.
I'd like to be able to collapse the responses to make it much quicker to scroll through my older prompts, only expanding them as needed.
I've been unable to find the option and wonder if anyone knows how to configure this.
